# Identifying bjt amplifier circuits configurations

Tags: transistors, amplifier, analog, bjt

how to identify configuration (CE or CB or EF) of this bjt amplifier circuit ?

[image: figure-from book microelectronic circuits]

in complex circuits (bjt amplifier), most  of the times I have this problem of figuring out its configuration.

My approach  to find configuration is

1. to check which terminal is grounded or common, or
2. to check  terminals between  which   ac signal is applied  and  terminals between  which load is  applied

and based on that  we can guess its configuration.

I am not sure whether  my approach is correct or not, because  I still  am not able to figure out configuration of complex circuits (as given in figure).

When I try to determine configuration of Circuit(in figure) I follow these steps-

using 1st method that I mentioned no terminal is grounded so I didn't reach to any conclusions

using 2nd method it seems like ac signal is applied between base and emitter but I cannot understand whether load is connected between base and emitter or emitter and Collector and that's it where I got stuck I don't know how to proceed further?

Is there any general rules to  identify configuration of complex amplifier circuits and we can tell its configuration just by looking at it?

Comment: I'd say both your techniques are usable determining that circuit, and they both give same answer. What have you determined so far about that circuit and where are you stuck?

Comment: How about both 1. and 2. being correct at the same time? The given circuit isn't complex, is the load connected to the collector or the emitter? So then that node isn't common. You're overthinking this.

Comment: Your described approach is helpful. What is your problem with this specific circuit? You should be able to figure it out using the mentioned approach pretty easily.

Comment: @Justme,@Lars Hankeln , using 1st method that I mentioned no terminal is grounded so I didn't reach to any conclusions                                                        using 2nd method  it seems like ac signal is applied between base and emitter but I cannot understand whether load is connected between base and emitter or emitter and Collector and that's it where I got stuck  I don't know how to proceed further?

Comment: Repeat your first method using AC analysis rules. One of the terminals IS grounded as far as AC is concerned.

Comment: Just a question : where does this schematic come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods that you described are useful for identifying the single transistor amplifier configuration.

In the first approach, you can identify the amplifier configuration by one transistor terminal being connected to small signal ground. So this could be the actual GND symbol or a constant potential like VCC in this example.

Your second approach tries to identify the signal input and output terminal of the transistor. Once those terminals are identified, the remaining terminal is the common terminal. In this case, the input signal is applied to the base and the output terminal is connected to the emitter. Forget about the reference point when using this approach. In the end, input and output signal can be referenced to the common terminal anyway.

Both approaches lead to the same result.

Comment: Thanks for answer! But since base is connected to ground via small signal and Collector is at Vcc  so how we conclude that it is common collector not common base?And in second method as you mentioned that forget about reference but isn't   load is connected between emitter and Collector so load should be at a Vcc potential instead of ground?

Comment: You might want to take a look at small signal analysis in general to understand it better. Amplifier circuit analysis is often split into large signal analysis (DC bias) and small signal analysis (signal properties of the amplifier). A constant voltage basically represents a (small) signal ground thus making this a common collector.